# Dynamic variables in Database Project views

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a Database Project with some views.

The views should behave differently depending on the environment they are published to.

When published to the development environment, the INNER JOINs should use a specific prefix for target schema name, and another prefix on the test environment.

Is it possible to achieve this? In the below code snippet, id like to use Hub when developing locally and when publishing to the dev envrionment, and ISA when published to test.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW [ISA].[v_CoveredRisk]
    AS SELECT
                CR.Bkey_CoveredRisk_Unique
                ,CO.Bkey_Coverage_Unique
                ,CO.Name
                ,PO.EKey_Policy
                ,CoObj.Bkey_CoveredObject
                ,CoObj.BKey_Building
                ,CoObj.Bkey_Home
                ,CoObj.BKey_Object
                ,CoObj.BKey_Person
                ,CoObj.BKey_Pet
                ,CoObj.BKey_Vehicle
                ,Risk_Excess
                ,Risk_Sum
                ,CAST(CurrentYearPremiumAmount AS float) AS CurrentYearPremiumAmount
                ,IsActive
                ,PO.BKey_Policy
                ,CR.Record_Timestamp

     FROM Hub.[CoveredRisk] CR
     INNER JOIN Hub.Coverage CO ON CR.EKey_Coverage = CO.EKey_Coverage
     INNER JOIN Hub.CoveredObject CoObj ON CR.EKey_CoveredObject = CoObj.EKey_CoveredObject
     INNER JOIN Hub.[Policy] PO ON CR.EKey_Policy = PO.Ekey_Policy
```

Comment: How do you execute SQL queries from .NET?

Comment: I dont execute SQL queries from .NET - I publish the project by right clicking it and choosing target database. I would like the content of the view to be slightly different when publishing to development and test, if it is possible.

Comment: @Kenci You will likely get better answers by picking a more appropriate tag, doesn't seem to have anything to do with C#, neither in the way you create nor consume the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you should remove this requirement and have the code the same in all your databases. You are almost 100% guaranteed to make a mistake at some point regarding this and deploy something that doesn't work in a different environment.

If you do want to do this, you can do it with synonyms - in your view reference a synonym and have that pointing to the respective schema. You can't get a synonym to point to a schema directly but can objects within a schema so if you have:

- dev table devSchema.table
- prod table prodSchema.table

in dev, have a synonym like:

`create synonym Hub.table for devSchema.table`

then your view reference Hub.table and it will be resolved to the dev table.

Comment: I used synonyms for a while and then found out SSMS's Intellisense couldn't parse them (meaning my code had the red squigly lines and there was no autocomplete). I couldn't live in that world so I switched to using simple views. SQL can optimize those out pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

have a T4 template that generates your SQL script

in your template find out what environment you are running against... create output accordingly

to find out for which environment you need to generate the output, have a look at publishing profiles, and configuration specific variables (a.k.a. "conditional compilation symbols" in your project's build properties)

you can probe those in the T4 template

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in schema or object name. If you really want to achieve what you say, I can suggest you 2 ways:

1. You will not control it with variables but you'll control it with release configurations. You can use conditional statements in the sqlproj file. So, I've created 2 views:

   CREATE VIEW [HUB].[View1]
       AS SELECT 1 as one;

   CREATE VIEW [ISA].[View1]
       AS SELECT 1 as one;

Then in sqlproj file I do following thing:

```
<Build Include="View1.sql" />
<None Include="View1.sql"  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
<None Include="View1_1.sql" />
<Build Include="View1_1.sql"  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' " />
```

And then  just pick the right release configuration when you deploy
[image]

NOTE: You need include and exclude the same file from build to achieve that.

2. This is much simpler approach. Always create view with the same and move it to the proper schema in the publish script. For example:

   IF DB_NAME() = 'Dev' EXEC sp_rename ....